# VS2010 Load Testing: How can I perform custom action that is run once prior to each load test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, load, load-testing

Basically, I need to restart particular service prior to each load test being run and there is no problem with the restart itself. I've researched for a while and haven't found a way to put some action or script or just another load test, so that I can be sure it is performed before each load test and only one time per load test.

Any ideas regarding how to make it behave this way are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [LoadTest Plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and use the `LoadTestStarting` event to call a method that restarts your service.

```
public class Plugin : ILoadTestPlugin
{
    private LoadTest _loadTest;

    public void Initialize(LoadTest loadTest)
    {
        _loadTest = loadTest;
        _loadTest.LoadTestStarting += new System.EventHandler(loadTest_LoadTestStarting);
        _loadTest.LoadTestFinished += new System.EventHandler(loadTest_LoadTestFinished);
    }

    void loadTest_LoadTestStarting(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Restart your service
    }

    void loadTest_LoadTestFinished(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in the Load Test Editor right click on the root and select `Add Load Test Plug-in...` to add the Plug-In to your `Load Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, especially if you are calling something on the command-line anyway, is to specify a Setup script in the active TestSettings:

[image]