# VS2010 Load Test Run Prepare and Verify Once

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

We have a load test that runs of 100 concurrent users. We also have "Prepare" and "Verify" tests that we'd like to run just once at the beginning and end of the whole load test - NOT for each emulated user (*100) in the load test.

Can anyone please advise the easiest way to configure this?

Comment: I have already answered a similar question: [VS2010 Load Testing: How can I perform custom action that is run once prior to each load test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990917/vs2010-load-testing-how-can-i-perform-custom-action-that-is-run-once-prior-to-e/9991327#9991327). If you need extra help I can post more information.

Comment: Thanks Schaliasos but this seems like overkill for my requirement. I'm hoping that there's an easier way to achieve what I need. I'm not looking to trigger any external process - I simply need to execute a single test before and after the load test. I would have thought this would be a common requirement.

Comment: I think you misunderstood it. I will post an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [Load Test Plug-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and use the `LoadTestStarting` & `LoadTestFinished` events to call the methods you want:

```
public class Plugin : ILoadTestPlugin
{
    private LoadTest _loadTest;

    public void Initialize(LoadTest loadTest)
    {
        _loadTest = loadTest;
        _loadTest.LoadTestStarting += new System.EventHandler(loadTest_LoadTestStarting);
        _loadTest.LoadTestFinished += new System.EventHandler(loadTest_LoadTestFinished);
    }

    void loadTest_LoadTestStarting(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //call your prepare method
    }

    void loadTest_LoadTestFinished(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //call your verify method
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you Schaliasos