# Per-test sample data generation for load testing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, tfsbuild, load-testing

I have a set of load tests, each testing a specific section of Sharepoint site. How can I automate the generation of sample data prior to each test?

I know that load tests allow me to specify tests that are run before/after a specific virtual user's test mix, but those are meant for user-specific setup like logging on. I want to create sample data for *all* users.

I can put my setup code into the Team Build template, but that doesn't take into account whether the test using the sample data is in the test list being run or not. If I modify the test list, I would also need to modify the build template as well. I cannot put the setup code into a test that is run before the load test either, because load tests must be run with the .Net 4.0 framework while accessing Sharepoint's API requires 3.5.

I could rewrite my sample data generation logic with Powershell and start it from a .Net 4.0 unit test. Is it my best option or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Check these:  [VS2010 Load Test Run Prepare and Verify Once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946556/vs2010-load-test-run-prepare-and-verify-once),   [VS2010 Load Testing: How can I perform custom action that is run once prior to each load test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990917/vs2010-load-testing-how-can-i-perform-custom-action-that-is-run-once-prior-to-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you question is more TeamBuild related than SharePoint. For short, the best way how to setup (and teardown) testdata in SharePoint is using PoSh in conjunction with the Microsoft.PowerShell.SharePoint SnapIn.

You can start your PowerShell scripts from Everywhere in TeamBuild. That's actually how I extend the default TeamBuild template. I've create a single custom build template, this template contains numerous PoSh hooks. While setting up a new project you can easily hook your scripts everywhere you need.

To be really independent from any .NET FX version you could create your sampledata using REST DataServices (ListData.svc)