# Load testing Visual Studio, start up script / setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, load-testing

I was wondering if it was possible to have a start-up script before running any load tests? For example, perhaps to seed some data or clear anything down prior to the tests executing.

In my instance I have a mixed bag of designer and coded tests. Put it simply, I have:

- Two `coded` tests
- A `designer` created web test which points to these coded tests
- A `load test` which runs the designer

I have tried adding a class and decorating with the attributes `[TestInitialize()]`, `[ClassInitialize()]` but this code doesn't seem to get run.

Some basic code to show this in practice (see below). Is there a way of doing this whereby I can have something **run only the once before test run**?

```
[TestClass]
public class Setup  : WebTest
{
    [TestInitialize()]
    public static void Hello()
    {
        // Run some code
    }

    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Probably should also mention that on my coded tests I have added these attributes and they get ignored. I have come across a workaround which is to create a `Plugin`.

*EDIT*

Having done a little more browsing around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9991327/1134076) article on SO which shows how to implement a `LoadTestPlugin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio provides a way of running a script before and also after a test run. They are intended for use in deploying data for a test and cleaning up after a test. The scripts are specified on the ["Setup and cleanup"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx#VSTestSettingsSetupandCleanupScripts) page in the ".testsettings" file.

A load test plugin can contain code to run before and after any test cases are executed, also at various stages during test execution. The interface is that events are raised at various points during the execution of a load test. User code can be called when these events occur. The `LoadTestStarting` event is raised before any test cases run. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153(v=vs.120).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Prefer the plugin approach as it gives me a little more control and I think it is quite simply cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use NUnit you have SetUp/TearDown for a per test scope and TestFixtureSetUp/TestFixtureTearDown to do something similar for a class (TestFixture)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a hack, but you can place your code inside the static constructor of your test class as it will automatically run exactly once before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced:

```
[TestClass]
public class Setup  : WebTest
{
    static Setup()
    {
        // prepare data for test
    }

    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```